# Returning data from Model.find() function in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

first off I'd like to make clear that I'm new to node.js and this may sound like a silly question but, how am I supposed to return data out of model.find() function in mongoose ( eg. with a var.exports = var )?<

```html
const data = () =>
{
    MyModel.find().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        return(result);
    });
}

exports.data = data
```

Being the query asyncronous I'm not able to retrieve these data until the function is completed (so never). Is there anyway to return these informations in a variable eg:

```html
const retriever = require('../utils/test.js') //calling the exports file


test = retriever.data
console.log(test)
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

With promises you can achieve it as follows

```
const data = () => {
    return MyModel.find({});   
}

// using it in another function 
const result = await data();
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

**1.You can use a callback, as below**

```
const data = (callback) =>
{
    MyModel.find().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        //return(result);
        callback(results);//we pass in a function which will be used to pull out 
        //data
    });
}

exports.data = data
```

// THE AREA WHERE THIS CODE IS USED

```
const {data} = require('./to/data')

//show data 
 data(function (result) {
 console.log( result );// data from callback
 })
```

**2. using async/await promies**

```
const data = async () =>
{
   let results = await MyModel.find();
}
exports.data = data
```

ON USING THIS FUNCTION

```
const {data} = require('./to/data')

(async function () {
    let res = await data();
    console.log(res);
})()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will need these solution for further implementation :)